# How can I get the Laravel guzzle http status code for 429?

Tags: laravel, http, guzzle

Yes I understand there is an excess of limit. But I need to get the status code, not the error way. Instead, it throws this message at me. How can I get the HTTP status code?

```
return $response->getStatusCode();
```

This error comes;

```
GuzzleHttp\Exception\ClientException
    
Client error: `GET https://api.envato.com/v3/market/author/sale?code=xxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xx` 
resulted in a `429 Too Many Requests` response: 
{"error": "Rate limit exceeded. See https://build.envato.com/api/#rate-limit for documentation."}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem.

```
try {
    $response = (new \GuzzleHttp\Client)->get('https://api.envato.com/v3/market/author/sale?code=xxxx-ad9e-xxxx-8c04-4674f811dd51', [
        'headers' => [
            'Authorization' => 'Bearer qweqweqwe'
        ]
    ]);

    $json = json_decode((string) $response->getBody(), true);

    return $json;
} catch (ClientException $exception) {
    return $exception->getResponse()->getStatusCode();
}
```